# Multiple QSortFilterProxyModel performance optimization

Tags: qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

**TL;DR**

I want to group multiple datasets from a single table without increasing the performance
by optimizing the [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) or by iterating the table data model. (which is better in performance)

---

For example, the following main table:

```
+------+------+---------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Results |
+------+------+---------+
| a    | b    |       2 |
| a    | c    |       4 |
| v    | b    |       5 |
+------+------+---------+
```

Can output multiple aggregated datasets by specifying some grouping conditions
for example:

- Condition of group and sum "a" entries

  ```
  Dataset results => a = 6
  ```
- Condition of group and sum "ab" entries

  ```
  Dataset results => a = 2
  ```
- Condtion of group and sum `Col1`

  ```
  Dataset results => a = 2
                     V = 1
  ```

Each results dataset will be displayed in a proper table view.

I succeed to achieve this by implementing multiple [QSortFilerProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) for each group condition.
(I had to inherit the [QSortFilerProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) set the group condition and override the [filterAcceptsRow](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) function.)

**But**, the issue is with the performance, on a large dataset, and with multiple proxies 
the Qt proxy model will iterate (`filterAcceptsRow`) all the tables models X times which slow down in performance.

I want to create multiple datasets by iterating the model only once.

Is it possible to implement it by using the proxy model?

Or maybe I need to iterate the main table model by my self and to generate these custom models?

**Note**:
*In my opinion, it looks like impossible to implement it by using the `QSortFilerProxyModel`, because of the model indexing,
If I sore multiple datasets, each one can have different `rowCount()` and the model indexing will be broken*.

Comment: Are you actually sorting and filtering data, that is, only displaying the rows and columns that fulfil your conditions, or are you displaying the results of your conditions ? If it is the second I don't think QSortfilterProxyModel is the right thing to use.

Comment: @plover, I want to display the results of the conditions, also if the main table is filtered I want to filter the conditions results. What is the alternative to `QSortfilterProxyModel` for this task?

Comment: So the results of the conditions are static except for when the data changes or data is filtered out ? 
I would just have a different view/widget for the result that is only recalculated on 'dataChanged' signal of the model or when a new filter is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, everything you need to create a custom proxy is the `QAbstractItemModel`. You don't need to derive from the filtering proxy classes at all. How you implement such a model is up to you, but don't be confined by thinking that the proxy needs to actually be anything but an implementation of the abstract model. The proxy classes are for your convenience: when it is not convenient to use them - don't!

Furthermore, the viable approaches differ a bit depending on what sort of output arities you have. If each filter produces only one row of results, then having just one proxy generate all of them is fine - but you're viewing each single-row result in its own table view? Perhaps your UI demands that. If the groupings can produce multi-row data (e.g. `group on Col1`, `output sum(Results)`), then you'd need individual view into each of the result sets.

Then I'd create a common proxy that interfaces to the data source, but that proxy isn't used directly. In fact, this proxy is just a `QObject` and doesn't derive from `QAbstractItemModel` at all. Instead, it would create `QAbstractItemModel` instances, as views into the data. They would forward requests to the common proxy that has all the data necessary to fulfill the request under any condition.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try to implement the common proxy approach.